# Using Regular Expressions to Extract Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in the form: "xMyS"

I want to extract x and y in using the Javascript Regex expressions.

For example, if the string is

```
10M225S
```

I need 10 and 225 from this.

Also, the string might not have either of x or y part. For example it can be just `225S` or just `10M`.

EDIT: I tried things like `.match()`, but don't know how to extract values in the mentioned format.

EDIT: The regex I tried so far is `/(\w+)M(\w+)S/`, but it seems to only work for `10M225S` and not for `10M` and `225S`.

Comment: have you tried anything? where are you stuck?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you google "javascript regular expressions"?

Comment: Yes...I did google about it. Found about .match(), but can't seem to get it done.

Comment: [^A-Z] is the regular expression to match x and y

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var str = "10M255S"
var match = str.match(/^([0-9]*)M*([0-9]*)S*$/)
```

Then `match[1]` is `10` and `match[2]` is `255`

If `var str = "10M"`, then `match[1]` is `10` and if `var str = "255S"`, then `match[1]` is `255`

In any of the three cases, matches start from second element of the array `match`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But it gives same result for `10M` and `10S`. How would I distinguish?

Comment: True, it does. As per the question, you said you want to extract the `x` and/or `y`'s which are related to `M` and `S` respectively. If you supply same x and y values in the string, why do you want to distinguish between them (as both are same)?

Comment: And if you really want to distinguish between tose two, use the first element in `match` array, which gives the whole matched string.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the strings:

```js
var str = "10M225S"
var m = str.split("M")[0];
var s = str.split("M")[1].split("S")[0];

console.log("m >>> " + m);
console.log("s >>> " + s);
```

no need for regular expressions in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. But I need a regex approach.

Comment: @dsaket Why? Because it's homework? If so then it's likely your tutor has given you the documentation you need.

Comment: No..it's a situation I encountered when I was working on an app.

Answer (score 0):

K-Gun's answer makes sense if the pattern never varies,  however if 'M' and 'S' are simply placeholder examples for arbitrary text, then use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) **/\d+/g**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function fn() {
      var re = /\d+/g, // match digits, globally
        str = '10M225S',
        result = [],
        temp;
      // process successive matches
      while ((temp = re.exec(str)) !== null)
        result.push(temp[0]);

      document.getElementById("result").innerText = result.toString();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="fn()">
  <h1 id="result"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UDWyrGh6dmO7gkjG3bzk?p=preview) demonstrating the code.

The RegExp *re* will match runs of digits.  This will work regardless of any non-digit characters, e.g. it would match "10ZXZZ225FOZ".

Comment: it gives the same result for 10M and 10S. i.e. 10. How would I distinguish?

Comment: @dsaket have a look at the plunkr I linked because that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "10M255S"
var result = str.match(/([0-9])/g)

var value = []
result.map(res => {
  value += res
})
console.log(value)
```

Comment: Consider explaining your code, so OP and other future readers know what the purpose is and how it solved the problem.

Comment: Using `.map()` and not using the returned value? Did you want to use `forEach()`? And I'm not sure if it answers the question, as your current code returns a string like `10255`, not what OP wanted.